# Update Directive when Model-Service is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have lots of directives in my application like the following,

```
app.directive('MyDir',function(StudentModel){
      return{
        template : '<div>{{name}}</name>',
        link : function(scope){
              scope.name = StudentModel.name;
        }
      }
});
```

Here `StudentModel` is nothing but `angular service` which acts as `model` for my application. So whenever I update the `StudentModel` outside this `directive`(say in any `controller` or in another `direcitve`), how to make this `directive` to get updated?

I can use `$broadcast or $watch` to listen for the changes and update this directive. But since there are lots of places I have this kind of structure, i feel writing too much of events or watchers will affect the performance.

Is there a way where I can update all the `directives` those who uses same `model` get updated whenever the `model` is updated(in any part of application since `service are singleton`).

Comment: trying to fix this is going to be a bit of a challenge, because you have essentially unintentionally isolated the directive by the use of the link function.  The way these directives should have been written would be to put `StudentModel.name` directly into the template without using a link function at all.

Comment: the main reason these are isolated is because you have taken an object (`StudentModel`) and extracted one of it's properties (`name`) as a primitive, and stored the value of the primitive as a value on another object (`scope`). `scope.name` and `StudentModel.name` are two separate variables, which just happen to be set to the same value, but are not pointing to the same memory reference.

Comment: another way to fix this would be if your `StudentModel` exposed an object (i.e. `StudentModel.student`) instead of a primitive, and you used `student.name` in your template.